# Add controls to ol3-sidebar

Tags: javascript, openlayers, sidebar, geo, openlayers-5

I'm trying to add a control-button to one of my sidebar sessions but I don't know how to do that in openlayers. The control I want to put in the sidebar is a printDialog of the 'ol-ext' extension. I'll post the code I tried to use which was one that was made in leaflet. I appreciate possible help

HTML - Div of the session I want to insert the control

```
<div class="sidebar-pane" id="print">
                <h1 class="sidebar-header">Impressão<span class="sidebar-close"><i class="fa fa-caret-left"></i></span></h1>
        <p>Clique no botão a seguir para iniciar a Impressão</p>
        <br>
        <!-- place where I want to put the control -->
</div>
```

JS

```
var printControl = new ol.control.PrintDialog();
        printControl.setSize('A4');
        printControl.setOrientation('landscape');
        printControl.setMargin(15);
        map.addControl(printControl);

        //attempt to insert the button
        var htmlObject1 = printControl.getContainer();
        var a1 = document.getElementById('print')
        function setParent(el, newParent){
            newParent.appendChild(el);
        }
        setParent(htmlObject1, a1);
```

Comment: Use a standard <button> and call print method on click.

Comment: <button onclick="printControl.print()">print </button>

Comment: Thanks for the tip,but now I have two buttons one inside and one outside the sidebar and when I remove the button on the outside and the button that is inside it doesn't work anymore. do you know the reason? Sorry for the level of questions, I'm new to the JS and GIS business

Comment: Remove the one on the map with display none in your css...